# Unpivot multiple columns while keeping other columns untouched

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi I have a data table that looks like this:

[image]

I would like to convert it to something like this:

[image]

I have tried with no success. All the exmaples I found were with les columns to keep and unpivot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` with a virtual `VALUES` table to unpivot multiple columns

```sql
SELECT
  t.Category,
  t.Brand,
  t.Year,
  t.Quarter,
  v.Segma,
  v.Sales,
  v.Discount
FROM YourTable t
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (VALUES
    ('A', t.Sales_A, t.Discount_A),
    ('B', t.Sales_B, t.Discount_B),
    ('C', t.Sales_C, t.Discount_C)
) v(Segma, Sales, Discount);
```